# How to merge two data frames by an identifier combined of an id and an additional date-range identifier in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames of clinical studies - patients and their blood analysis values. I want to merge them on two identifiers, 1) on "PIZ" (which is the non-unique ID) from both data frames and 2) on Datum (Date) from data frame2 that should lie in a range of x days (say 7) between Datum_Implant (date1) and Datum_Explant (date2) in data frame1 (OP_Liste...). My final data table should be one from where it is possible to carry out survival/ event analysis with the event being the appearance of a "Keim" between Datum_Implan and Datum_Explant. Is this possible at all?

This is dataframe1 (OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2):

```
> dput(head(OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2, n = 20))
structure(list(PIZ = c(11364500, NA, 11612954, NA, 15597283, 
15597283, 15597283, 15597283, 17089951, NA, NA, 17134264, NA, 
17273329, 17947389, 17947389, 17947389, 18020912, 18020912, 18195470
), Datum = c("10/01/2001 13:16", NA, "20/06/2001 10:05", NA, 
"06/10/2004 08:15", "20/12/2004 10:03", "09/06/2005 12:20", "20/02/2006 12:58", 
"03/07/2003 07:33", NA, NA, "13/12/2000 09:45", NA, "11/03/2005 13:14", 
"11/11/2002 11:13", "06/11/2003 12:20", "15/01/2004 08:07", "06/08/2001 08:15", 
"24/09/2001 11:40", "05/10/2011 14:34"), Alter = c(13, NA, 18, 
NA, NA, 14, 14, 15, 12, NA, NA, 9, NA, 14, 12, 13, 13, 7, 7, 
16), Geschlecht = c("M", NA, "W", NA, NA, "M", "M", "M", "W", 
NA, NA, "M", NA, "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), Datum_Implant = c("10/01/2001 13:16", 
NA, "20/06/2001 10:05", NA, NA, "20/12/2004 10:03", "09/06/2005 12:20", 
"20/02/2006 12:58", "03/07/2003 07:33", NA, NA, "13/12/2000 09:45", 
NA, "11/03/2005 13:14", "11/11/2002 11:13", "06/11/2003 12:20", 
"15/01/2004 08:07", "06/08/2001 08:15", "24/09/2001 11:40", "05/10/2011 14:34"
), Datum_Explant = c("09/07/2001 12:20", "26/09/2001 15:25", 
"14/08/2001 08:13", "06/10/2004 08:15", NA, "07/04/2005", "24/10/2005 08:15", 
NA, "11/07/2003 12:10", "12/12/2003 07:39", "24/03/2004 11:00", 
"28/03/2001 12:30", "30/12/2002 07:45", NA, "14/07/2003 08:30", 
"04/01/2004 15:00", "12/07/2004 10:24", NA, "03/05/2002 10:50", 
NA), KatheterNummer = c(1, 2, 1, NA, NA, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), problems = structure(list(
    row = c(1102L, 1223L, 1624L, 1949L, 2092L, 2180L, 2283L, 
    2308L, 2406L, 2593L, 2605L, 2607L, 2608L, 2648L, 2652L, 2687L, 
    2706L, 2709L, 2745L, 2770L, 2792L, 2816L, 2821L, 2861L, 2867L, 
    2869L, 2877L, 2884L, 2886L, 2894L, 2897L, 2904L, 2912L, 2914L, 
    2916L, 2928L, 2934L, 2937L, 2944L, 2952L, 2953L, 2954L, 2956L, 
    2964L, 2967L, 2975L, 2979L, 2989L, 2991L, 2996L, 2998L, 2999L, 
    3009L, 3013L, 3017L, 3033L, 3037L), col = c("An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", 
    "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung", "An<e4>sthesie Einleitung"), 
    expected = c("1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", 
    "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE"), actual = c("0.496527778", "0.536111111", 
    "0.576388889", "0.524305556", "0.569444444", "0.583333333", 
    "0.440972222", "0.5875", "0.581944444", "0.602083333", "0.613194444", 
    "0.350694444", "0.479166667", "0.388888889", "0.5625", "0.333333333", 
    "0.423611111", "0.4375", "0.316666667", "0.621527778", "0.479166667", 
    "0.409722222", "0.40625", "0.322222222", "0.416666667", "0.392361111", 
    "0.473611111", "0.475", "0.354861111", "0.558333333", "0.361111111", 
    "0.600694444", "0.357638889", "0.429861111", "0.590277778", 
    "0.427083333", "0.511111111", "0.434027778", "0.40625", "0.329861111", 
    "0.48125", "0.534722222", "0.49375", "0.502083333", "0.559027778", 
    "0.458333333", "0.585416667", "0.556944444", "0.572916667", 
    "0.614583333", "0.572916667", "0.591666667", "0.590277778", 
    "0.5", "0.524305556", "0.59375", "0.575"), file = c("'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", 
    "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'", "'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Joachim.csv'"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -57L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is data frame 2 (Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen):

```
> dput(head(Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen, n = 20))
structure(list(`Pat-ID` = c("10284279", "10826080", "10826080", 
"10826080", "10826080", "11170706", "11364500", "11626742", "11626742", 
"15190779", "15190779", "15190779", "15190779", "15390980", "15390980", 
"15390980", "15597283", "15597283", "15597283", "15597283"), 
    Datum = c("22.05.2003", "23.01.2000", "23.01.2000", "25.01.2000", 
    "25.01.2000", "26.03.2003", "18.02.2001", "25.04.2002", "31.12.2001", 
    "01.04.2008", "01.04.2008", "31.03.2008", "31.03.2008", "13.05.2000", 
    "26.06.2000", "26.06.2000", "01.06.2006", "01.06.2006", "07.04.2005", 
    "12.05.2006"), Zeit = c("00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", 
    "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", 
    "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", 
    "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", "00:00:00", 
    "00:00:00", "00:00:00"), Keim = c("Staphylococcus capitis", 
    "Staphylococcus aureus", "Staphylococcus aureus", "Staphylococcus aureus", 
    "Staphylococcus aureus", "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken", 
    "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken", "Escherichia coli", "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken", 
    "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken", "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken", 
    "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken", "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken", 
    "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken", "Citrobacter freundii", "Citrobacter freundii", 
    "Enterococcus faecium", "Enterococcus faecium", "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken", 
    "Koagulase neg.Staphylokokken"), Material = c("Blutkultur FAN anaerob, Ascites", 
    "Blutkultur aerob", "Blutkultur anaerob", "Blutkultur aerob", 
    "Blutkultur anaerob", "ZVK-Spitze", "Blutkultur aerob", "Blutkultur - ZVK  aerob", 
    "ZVK-Spitze, Exit", "Blutkultur aerob, ZVK", "Blutkultur anaerob, ZVK", 
    "Blutkultur - AE Schenkel  rot", "Blutkultur - AE Schenkel weiß", 
    "Blutkultur aerob", "Blutkultur aerob", "ZVK-Spitze", "Blutkultur aerob", 
    "Blutkultur anaerob", "ZVK-Spitze", "Blutkultur aerob")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So I tried this:

```
names(Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen)[names(Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen) == "Pat-ID"] <- "PIZ"

library(dplyr)
Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen <- Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen %>% select (PIZ, Datum, Keim)

Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen <- Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen %>% group_by(PIZ, Datum) %>% filter(row_number()==1)

library(lubridate)
Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen$Datum_Mibi <- as.Date(Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen$Datum, "%d.%m.%Y")
Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen$Datum_Mibi <- decimal_date(Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen$Datum_Mibi)

Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen$Event <- 1


OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2 <- OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020 %>% select (PIZ, Datum, Alter, Geschlecht, Datum_Implant, Datum_Explant, KatheterNummer)

head(OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2, n= 20)

library(data.table)

Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen <- as_tibble(Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen)

Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen$Datum_neu <- as.Date(Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen$Datum, "%d.%m.%Y")
OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2$Datum_neu <- as.Date(OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2$Datum, "%d/%m/%Y")


setDT(Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen)[, application_date := Datum_neu]

setDT(OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2)

OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2$PIZ <- as.character(OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2$PIZ)

y <- Mibi_Blutkultur_ZVK_mit_Keimen[OP_Liste_5_399_01012000_bis_01012020_2, on = .(PIZ, Datum_neu = Datum_neu), roll = 'nearest']
```

It seems to be rather close to my desired solution but sometimes I get negative values. Is this a data or a programming problem? Also, any link to how to create complex clinical trials tables would be very much appreciated.

Comment: look into non-equi joins

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may get a better response if you could create a minimal example [reprex]  which illustrates the problem